# Messenger not loading Dialogflow Cards with certain urls

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chat

I am trying to add a card in my intent with a button that links to the following URL: [LINK](https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/acoes-da-vale-sobem-com-contratacao-de-linha-de-credito-de-r-3-bi-embraer-cai-e-technos-dispara-11/)

However, when it's triggered in Facebook Messenger, the card loads but never shows. If I change the url to other links (such as Google's) it works as expected, but if it is a link from the same website (Infomoney) it doesn't.

[Image of the Dialogflow card with the button URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekK97.png)

Comment: Have you tried to whitelist the domain ? In Facebook page settings, messenger section you can add domains to whitelist

Comment: Yes, I've tried to add the domain to the whitelist but it still won't work for this specific website.